# How to output data in multipleSelect to laravel-admin form?

Tags: php, laravel

Model - **Promo**:

```
...
    protected $table = 'promo';
...
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cities::class, 'cities_promo');
    }
```

Controller in laravel-admin

```
...
    protected function form()
    {
        $location = Cities::pluck('name', 'id');

        $form = new Form(new Promo);

        $form->text('title', __('Title'));
        $form->textarea('desc', __('Description'));
        $form->multipleSelect('locations')->options($location);

        return $form;
    }
...
```

The bottom line is that it does not display the values that were previously selected and saved. An empty field is displayed there, where you can select values from the City model.

Answer (score 1):

An intermediate solution was to use the attribute.
It is necessary that the format for **multipleSelect** (and others) was in array format *`[1,2,3 ... ,7]`*.

In normal communication, an array of the form is transmitted:

```
{
['id' => 1,
'name' => 'Moscow',
...
],
['id' => 2,
'name' => 'Ekb',
...
],
}
```

Therefore, for formalization, I used a third-party attribute "**Cities**" to the model "**Promo**".

```
...
    //Add extra attribute
    //These attributes will be written to the database, if you do not want 
    //this, then do not advertise!
    //protected $attributes = ['cities'];

    //Make it available in the json response
    protected $appends = ['cities'];
    public function getCitiesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->locations->pluck('id');
    }

    public function setCitiesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->locations()->sync($value);
    }
```

If there are other suggestions, I am ready to listen.
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

change $location to

```
$location = Cities::All()->pluck('name', 'id');
```

you can `return $location` to know it has value or not

also you can set options manually

```
$form->multipleSelect('locations')->options([1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 'val' => 'Option name']);
```

to know it works

Comment: Yes, the recording is in success. But after saving, when editing data is not displayed. (There is a connection in the database).